# Finding where the foreach Loop is at

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to find where the current foreach Loop is at so, I can handle the foreach loop differently based on its current status. if it's in groupbox1 or groupbox2.

```
        int Name = 1;
        string Usernames = @"C:\UPHhour\names.txt";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Usernames, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            var Names = groupBox1.Controls.Cast<Control>().Concat(groupBox2.Controls.Cast<Control>());
            foreach(Control OLR_FF in Names.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
            {                   
               if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OLR_FF.Text.ToString()))
                {
                    //if the foreach loop is in groupbox1
                    if(OLR_FF is groupbox1)
                    {                           
                        //do something
                    }
                    // or if its in groupbox2 
                    if(OLF_FF is groupbox2) 
                    {
                        //do something different.
                    }
                    //sw.WriteLine("Name"+ Name++ + "=" + OLR_FF.Text.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

How do I go about knowing if the loop is in groupbox1 or is in groupbox2?

Comment: If you don't actually want to do the same thing to both sequences, then don't concat them together in the first place.

Comment: `if(OLR_FF.Parent == groupbox1)`, `==` instead of `is`

Comment: @Servy I would agree with you if it was not for the `.OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex)` in the `foreach`, doing two separate `foreach` would not process the items in tab order if the order jumped back and forth between the two group boxes.

Comment: I didn't want to use two different `foreach` to achieve the same results but i needed to change one thing based on which `groupbox` the  `foreach` was in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Control.Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) property then check if the parent equals one of the two group boxes

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OLR_FF.Text.ToString()))
{
    //if the foreach loop is in groupbox1
    if(groupbox1.Equals(OLR_FF.Parent))
    {                           
        //do something
    }
    // or if its in groupbox2 
    else if(groupbox2.Equals(OLF_FF.Parent))
    {
        //do something different.
    }
    //sw.WriteLine("Name"+ Name++ + "=" + OLR_FF.Text.ToString());
}
```

Comment: lol. StackOverflow was like I must wait 7 minutes before I can mark as answered.